# Use Wrappanel in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, wrappanel, longlistselector

I am currently using the LongListSelector from the latest release of the Silverlight Toolkit. What I now want to do, is to arrange several items in one line, just like in the Wrappanel, but I don't know how to do so. Is it possible with the LongListSelector? I know how to horizontally align items in common list, but I don't want to miss the features of the LongListSelector.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned, The WrapPanel (part of the Silverlight Toolkit) doesn't support virtualization, so you will get a huge performance hit when you want to display to many items. Regarding your question, you want to style / template your LongListSelector. I think they even have an example within the Silverlight Toolkit source code download. Have a look at that.